# 403 forbidden webhook request on ngrok

Tags: javascript, backend, webhooks, strapi

I want to get JSON from Razorpay webhook and I am using NEXT.JS in frontend and Strapi on the backend to develop my site. Because webhook doesn't work locally, I have tunneled my localhost to HTTPS using ngrok. Whenever webhook sends me data on ngrok URL, the ngrok shows me **403 Forbidden requests by webhook**.

This is my code:

```
async verification(ctx) {
    try {
      ctx.send(200);
      const secret = "This is the razorpay secret";

      console.log(ctx.request.body);
    } catch {
      error;
    }
  },
```

I am sending 200 and printing the JSON that webhook sends me. I see nothing wrong and it's still not working. On the NGROK web interface, I can see the JSON webhook send me but ngrok tells me that request webhook made is forbidden and gives the status of 403.